# Kubuntu 12.04 - DNS Issues

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, network-manager, dns, resolv.conf

Starting yesterday (6/11/12), I've been having many network problems. When requesting a page in chrome, the page hangs on "Sending request" and then will eventually timeout. I'm within a VPN that has it's own DNS server. I've tried to manually set my DNS through the Network-Manager applet and by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`. Having no luck I unlinked the resolv.conf file and dumped the contents of my old resolv.conf into it. Again having no luck, I deactivated the dnsmasq server in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` by commenting out the `dns=dnsmasq`.

```
$ cat NetworkManager.conf 

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
#dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=D0:67:E5:EA:B6:6B,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        D0:67:E5:EA:B6:6B

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.254.122
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.254.2

    DNS:             192.168.254.1
```

What is strange is that the network will work fine for a few minutes then start to timeout. A few minutes later it will work again. I'm unable to hit internal or external sites when it is timing out. When I `$dig` local sites, I receive no answer. I do receive an answer from google.com.

At this point, I would usually blame the DNS Server, especially since when I change to Google's DNS server things work. But, I need to use our internal DNS to hit our internal sites. Nobody else is having issues and they are all using DHCP. This group includes one user who is using 11.04.

At this point, I'm at a loss for what to do, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error it appears the network card is bad.