# Problem with DNS in the latest Kubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns

Today I install Kubuntu 16.04, again, because I'm having trouble to navigate. I have tried all kinds of browser, and with all I have the same problem.

Sometime when I open a page, I received these message "ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED". Once every three pages that I open, I get this problem.

This problem, was not happening, after the installation and before I update the system.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using a ethernet connection. And the strange part is that if I use a Wifi connections, this problem will not happen......

Comment: Since it doesn't fail always I would assume that connectivity is good but the DNS server you are using may be overloaded.

Comment: But these issue it's only in my Kubuntu, and not in the other computer connected to the same network.....

Comment: Interesting. Are you obtaining DNS via DHCP or statically? Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150084/kubuntu-12-04-dns-issues?rq=1

Comment: Right now I'm doing it via DHCP. I have all ready tried using google DNS, but it's the same.....

Comment: Any related errors in the logs? If so please [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Possibly related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1578533

Comment: folowing the solution from this thread works for me
https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error

Answer (score 3):

You can test network connectivity with `ping` command:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

if you get reply from Google public DNS, then you have connected to internet and maybe you haven't set DNS in your ethernet interface. go to **Network Connections** and then Edit your ethernet interface. change the tab to **IPV4 Settings** and set DNS in **Additional DNS Servers** field like `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done that, change the DNS to the public google DNS, but the problem persist....... I tried with the ping tools to 8.8.8.8, and my coneection is ok..... It's the weird network problem that I ever had......

Comment: Are you get reply from this command? : `nslookup google.com`

Comment: If no reply recieved, check this command: `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find google.com: REFUSED
This is what I recived, when I do nslookup google.com.

Comment: Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.190.139
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.190.101
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.190.138
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.190.113
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.190.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.190.102
This is what I get when I do nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8

Comment: Open `/etc/resolv.conf`, erase all content and then add `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. save and close the file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the latest 16.04 updates.
Fixed as follows:

1. Remove (or comment out) the below line from /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:
   dns=dnsmasq
2. Run service NetworkManager restart